# How to use Cron to run commands when jobs in a particular folder complete?

Tags: command-line, cluster-computing, cron

I am running a long simulation on our cluster. I submit dozens of jobs first, each job is "hold on" its previous one, so that the simulation could be extended to the period that I want.

Due to the limitation of total jobs we could submit, I have to submit many jobs every day, when the previous jobs have been completed.

I feel it is time-consuming to do this every day. So I wonder if Cron could

1. monitor if all the jobs launched in a particular folder have been
   completed on the cluster
2. if yes, execute the commands written in a job.sh file, to submit
   more jobs within that particular folder.

I am also happy if other methods could be used except Cron.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in trying [BeyondCron](http://beyondcron.com), which is currently available for early adopters. Using [conditions](http://beyondcron.com/post/2016/02/18/schedules-triggers-conditions.html) you should be able to solve you problem.

Comment: Project affiliations should always be noted.

Comment: @DaveNewton   thank you. Sorry, I am not familiar with this, should I use "Docker"? http://beyondcron.com/products/

Comment: Unless you are already using Docker, I suggest using the enterprise version which installs as daemons on your own servers - http://beyondcron.com/download/

Disclosure: I am the founder of BeyondCron